# .Net core IHostedService Background task exception will not terminate application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that needs to terminate when an IHostedService background task encounters a certain scenario. I was hoping to do this by just throwing an exception in the background task that would get kicked up to the main function. I could then trigger the cancellation token to kill other background tasks.
My problem is that when I throw the exception, it kills the task and that's all. Everything else keeps running. Is there a way to do this, or a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Is there another way to have a backgrounds task trigger the common CancellationToken?

I included a simplified version of my issue in the code below. 
If I comment out the `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), stoppingToken);` line, the exception does what I want and I can trigger the CancellationToken. When it is in place, the task stops, but the program does not.

NOTE: In my messier code I have more IHostedServices running, which is why I'm trying to trigger `cancelSource.Cancel()`

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            try
            {
                await new HostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddHostedService<TestService>();
                    })
                    .Build()
                    .RunAsync(cancelSource.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                cancelSource.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class TestService : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), stoppingToken);
            Console.WriteLine("loop 1");
            throw new ApplicationException("OOPS!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Commenting the only line in the `ExecuteAsync` method with `await` operator makes your code run synchronously. If we look at the sources of [`BackgroundService.StartAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs#L30), we can see that it checks for `_executingTask.IsCompleted` and it returns task that will contain your exception in case we don't have any await in `ExecuteAsync` method, otherwise it will return `Task.CompletedTask` and you won't be able to catch this exception from `ExecuteAsync` in `Main` method.

You can manage your services with [IApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iapplicationlifetime-interface) that can be injected in all your background services. For example, you can catch exception within `ExecuteMethod` and call `ApplicationLifetime.StopApplication`.

Example:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<TestService>();
            services.AddHostedService<TestService2>();
        })
        .Build()
        .RunAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("App stoped");
}
```

Service 1

```
public class TestService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;
    public TestService(IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        _applicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!_applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping);
                Console.WriteLine("running service 1");
                throw new ApplicationException("OOPS!!");
            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            _applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
        }
    }
}
```

Service 2

```
public class TestService2 : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;
    public TestService2(IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        _applicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!_applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100, _applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping);
                Console.WriteLine("running service 2");
            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            _applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
running service 2
running service 2
running service 1
App stoped
```

Comment: this answer is what I was looking for, but looks like `IApplicationLifetime` is deprecated in favor of `IHostApplicationLifetime`.